# Regular expression for calculator with decimal point

Tags: ios, regex, nsregularexpression

I am making a calculator application and want to validate my input in the form:

```
operand operator operand
```

These operands may also contain decimal points. I am not able to make a regular expression for it. I have tried this expression:

```
@"^[-+]?(\\.[0-9])+([-+*/]+[-+]?(\\.[0-9])+)*$"
```

But this is not working. Can anyone suggest solution for it?

Comment: FYI - don't forget that not all users use the decimal point `.` for the decimal separator.

Comment: This part (\\.[0-9])+ expects a decimal point then a number, such as .1 or .3.5.9, it won't find a number of the form 123.456.

Comment: What number representations do you deem legal? Would you accept all of the following: 0.123 , 45 , 12. , .34 ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check this regular expression, this will works.

```
^[-+]?([0-9]+)[\\.0-9]+[-+*/+][-+]?([0-9]+)[\\.0-9]*$
```

Also if you want to make change in future below link is a good tool to test regular expression.

https://www.debuggex.com/

Comment: This number pattern `[0-9.0-9]+` can be done as '[\d.]', you don't need to specify the range 0-9 twice between brackets. Also, this pattern will incorrectly find numbers that contain multiple decimal points: 123....35.234.297.

Comment: The decimal point needs to be backslashed, it currently takes any character, so 123&456 would be accepted as a number.

Comment: Decimal point should be outside the brackets, for example it will accept: 123...234.978

Comment: this works but not in case when we enter a simple expression without decimal point

Answer (score 0):

Try changing your pattern for finding a number from

```
(\\.[0-9])+
```

to

```
\\d+\\.?\\d*
```

Note, this pattern will require a number before the decimal point, and numbers such as 123. or 000. will still be found.